# Adding overlay to mapview (beginner)

Tags: java, android, google-maps, dictionary, android-mapview

I have the following code, but the overlay doesn't seem to be visible on the map, although the focus is on the desired geo points.
Here's the code:

```
   public void setOverlay()
{
    MapView mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.getController().setCenter(place.getGeoPoint());
    List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    MyItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay = new MyItemizedOverlay(drawable);
    OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(place.getGeoPoint(), "Hola, Mundo!", "I'm in Mexico City!");
    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
    mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);


}
```

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call:

```
mapView.invalidate();
```

To force the redraw of overlays after you add them to `MapView`. Add the line above to the bottom of your method and it should work (I´m assuming that your icon is not fully transparent :-), in that case you will not see it in anyway)

Regards.

Comment: Uhm, it still not working. I will try fix it later on, it's weird.

Comment: The code above looks fine. If it doens't appear, check the following: 1 - that you are realy calling `setOverlay()` and `place` has the correct value. Map always starts in the last position used and you may be thinking it's center corretly. 2 - Check `MyItemizedOverlay` class.